# Specialized RNNs and sequential output in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement an RNN decoder for an NER task (specifically the decoder step in the model from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05928v1)) in Keras.  To implement it, I need to feed the output at time step t to the input of time step t+1.  If I'm understanding the Keras docs and Github discussions correctly, this is not possible with base Keras (but please correct me if I'm wrong here).  I've found [Recurrentshop](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/recurrentshop), which appears to have the functionality I want, but I haven't been able to get it working.  If anyone has other thoughts on a good approach (e.g. building a custom layer), that is certainly welcome.

I suspect I'm having trouble getting Recurrentshop working because I am unclear on how to handle output sequences in Keras.  For example, if the last layer of my model is an `LSTM` layer with `output_sequences=True`, and `activation='softmax'` and I fit with `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function, does Keras know to compare each time step of the output with each time step of ground truth labels and sum the losses?  Or do I need to use `TimeDistributed` on my output layer?

As a concrete example, let's say the output of the encoder layers has 100 time steps per example, and 10 features per time step:

```
input_from_encoder_layers = Input(shape=(100, 10))
my_decoder_lstm_output = MyDecoderLSTM(50, activation='softmax')(input_from_encoder)
```

The goal is to extract one label per time step for every example.  To sum up my confusion here, I don't know what is the best way to implement `MyDecoderLSTM` in Keras, and I'm unclear on how to handle sequences as the last layer in a Keras model.  Thanks!